# Is it possible to have a constructor on a generic class that introduces additional generic types?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to build a generic class whose constructor introduces an additional type, but the compiler says no-no.

I don't quite understand why the following doesn't work:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo<T,TBar>(TBar tBar)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

It's not critical as I can write the class using a fluent api (which might be preferred), but I'd still like to understand why I can't.  The only explanation I can think of is that the compiler doesn't like method-level generic type declaration mixed with class-level generic type declaration.

Comment: You can't, you need to use a factory method.

Comment: Not really a duplicate question, but [Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3606951/743382) to a related question illustrates what sort of problems the language designers would need to solve before this would be possible. (Actually, perhaps it is a duplicate question. I'm not sure if your question focuses more on the "is it possible", or on the "why isn't it possible".)

Comment: It might actually be another way of approaching the question you referenced.  There's definitely a practical question ('is it possible') probing for an academic response ('and why not?'). I like the factory method approach here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible. The constructor is not called like a method, it is invoked by specifying the class name only (after the `new` keyword). Normal methods, on the other hand, can have additional generic type arguments.

Comment: You beat JS to the answer by a minute and they're both succinct with some explanation so I'm marking this as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. Only types and methods can be generic. You can't have generic properties, events, fields, constructors or finalizers.

Note that this has nothing to do with whether the containing type is generic or not - it's just a limitation of the language (and CLR, I suspect), basically. (Interestingly, Java *does* allow generic constructors - but generics in Java are pretty different to those in C# anyway.)

Comment: "It's just a limitation of the language" certainly suffices.  I feel like if there were overwhelming demand for this feature they could write it into the compiler no problem.  But it's not exactly an elegant or highly useful feature so the limitation is imposed rather than not feasible.

Comment: @BlackjacketMack: I'm not sure whether it could easily be done *just* in the C# compiler. I suspect it's a limitation of the language *and* the CLR. Making it work nicely in C# when not supported by the CLR could be tricky. But yes, it's a choice rather than a fundamental impossibility.

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly possible, as Jon himself pointed out, but there is a common workaround, that solves the problem:

```
public class Foo<T,TBar>
{
    public Foo(TBar tBar)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

IIUC, the call to `new` for this is just as you wanted it

Comment: Creating an object now requires `new Foo<T, TBar>(tBar)` instead of `new Foo<T>(tBar)`, it doesn't allow `TBar` to be deduced from the argument's type.

Comment: Which means, that my "IIUC" is falsified. I stand corrected. Still not deleting this answer, as others myight make the same mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the idea though...I think Pragmateek's idea of a factory method would be a cleaner approach though without changing the overall type.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is a special method. Have you ever noticed the parantheses coming after the name of the class and the `new` keyword?

```
Person jack = new Person();
```

The `Person();` has a method call syntax. This is because it's not the type `Person`, but a method named exactly as the type itself, due to the design of the language to be called to initialize the type.

Quoting from C# specification:

> The identifier of a constructor-declarator shall name the class in which the instance constructor is declared. If any other name is specified, a compile-time error occurs.

and

> 17.10 Instance constructors
>   An instance constructor is a member that implements the actions required to initialize an instance of a class. Instance constructors are declared using constructor-declarations:

And if you look at the constructor formula, you don't see any generic declaration token at all:

> constructor-declarator:
>      identifier ( formal-parameter-listopt ) constructor-initializeropt

Comment: None of this would prohibit there being such a thing as a generic constructor though. It so happens that it's not supported, but it could be supported and everything in your answer would still be the case...

Comment: Yeah @JonSkeet, you're right. I just updated the answer. Thanks for noticing.