# Generic enum as method parameter

Tags: c#, generics, enums

Given a constructor

```
public MyObject(int id){
    ID = id;
}
```

And two enums:

```
public enum MyEnum1{
    Something = 1,
    Anotherthing = 2
}

public enum MyEnum2{
    Dodo = 1,
    Moustache= 2
}
```

Is it possible to pass in a generic enum as a parameter of the constructor?  I'm looking for a solution along the lines of:

```
public MyObject(enum someEnum){
    ID = (int)someEnum;
}
```

So you can do:

```
var newObject = new MyObject(MyEnum1.Something);
var anotherObject = new MyObject(MyEnum2.Dodo);
```

Comment: You can receive the parameter as Integer, and convert your enums to Integers when you pass them.

Comment: [You can't do a generic constructor in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3606951/424129). The best you could do is to write a nongeneric base class with a generic subclass, then make the enum type a type parameter for the generic subclass. Awkward. `MyBase b = new MySub<EnumA>(EnumA.SomeValue); int n = b.ID;`

Comment: MyObject(MyEnum1 enum1Selection){} but integer is better

Comment: `new MyObject((int)MyEnum1.Something);` ?

Comment: upvote @SuperPeanut, but, I would create a "objectType" `enum` and pass that to a factory that in turn creates the right thing with the right `enum` parameter.  `var newObject = myFactory.Create(ObjectType.One)`.

Comment: ... Alternatively, overload the constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you want to pass the enums, while you could pass integers ?

```
var newObject = new MyObject((int)MyEnum1.Something);
var anotherObject = new MyObject((int)MyEnum2.Dodo);
```

and use your first constructor :

```
public MyObject(int id){
    ID = id;
}
```

Comment: Yup this is what I was doing already, would just look more readable if I could pass the enum in directly

Comment: If it is about readability, you can use @HimBromBeere [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39392579/5897829) with a generic constructor, you have to write the enum name twice but it looks all right... All depends on what you want

Comment: Because Enum can have attribute `Flags`

Answer (score 10):

Another option would be:

```
public MyObject(Enum someEnum){
    ID = Convert.ToInt32(someEnum);
}
```

This way you can use it like you requested without having to cast to `int` each time you call your contstructors:

```
var newObject = new MyObject(MyEnum1.Something);
var anotherObject = new MyObject(MyEnum2.Dodo);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use a generic constructor:

```
class MyObject<T> {

    public MyObject(T someEnum) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) 
            throw new ArgumentException("Not an enum");
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(someEnum);
    }
}
```

Now you can easily call it like this:

```
var m = new MyObject<MyEnum>(MyEnum1.Something);
```

But easier would be to pass the enum as integer to the constructor as mentioned in other answers.

EDIT: As of C# 7.3 you can use an enum-constraint right away:

```
class MyObject<T> where T: Enum { ... }
```

Comment: You know you can't use Enum as a constraint? Life would be easier if you could but it won't compile.

Comment: @Ben You´re right, I updated the answer appropriately. Unfortunately you´re loosing compiler-type check against `Enum` with this approach making it possible to pass instances of `int` to the method as well.

Comment: I am painfully aware of this. My day has been spent trying to find as robust of a solution as possible. But sadly the above is about as good as you'll get!

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you really need to make this call generic for a wide variety of types, then IMHO you should use:

1. [Type.IsEnum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum.aspx) to check if your argument is really an `Enum`;
2. [Enum.GetUnderlyingType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx) to know what type is your argument is based on (it's not necessarily an `Int32`);
3. Now cast your object.

   ```
   public static Int32 GetAnInt<T>(T arg) where T : struct
   {
       if ((typeof(T).IsEnum))
       {
           var underlyingType = typeof(T).GetEnumUnderlyingType();
           if (underlyingType == typeof(Int32)
           || underlyingType == typeof(Int16)) //etc.
           {
               try
               {
                   dynamic value = arg;
                   var result = (Int32)value; // can throw InvalidCast!
                   return result;
               }
               catch
               {
                   throw;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               throw new InvalidCastException("Underlying type
                            is certainly not castable to Int32!");
           }
       }
       else
       {
           throw new InvalidCastException("Not an Enum!");
       }
   }
   ```

   That way you achieve the beautiful syntax of: `var j = GetAnInt(MyEnum.FirstValue);`

Comment: And I'm almost certain you may add a lot of different checks and polish this code for years =)

Comment: And yes, it's easier to pass an integer.

Answer (score -2):

Are you using properties enum or parameters.

```
public enum Enum1{}
public Enum1 enum1 { get;set; }
public MyObject()
{
   ID = (int)enum1;
}
```

Just try it. I hope it is useful.

Comment: How exactly does it answer his question?

Comment: And what will you get accessing a member property from a constructor?